# Redshift copy command from S3 works, but no data uploaded

Tags: amazon-s3, copy, amazon-redshift

I am using the copy command to copy a file (.csv.gz) from AWS S3 to Redshift

copy sales_inventory from
's3://[redacted].csv.gz'
CREDENTIALS '[redacted]'
COMPUPDATE ON
DELIMITER ','
GZIP
IGNOREHEADER 1
REMOVEQUOTES
MAXERROR 30
NULL 'NULL'
TIMEFORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'
;

I don't receive any errors, just '0 rows loaded successfully'.  I checked the easy things: double checked the file's content, made sure I was targeting the right file with the copy command.  Then I created a simple one row example file to try and it didn't work.  I've been using a copy command template I made a long time ago and that has worked very recently.

Any common mistakes I might have overlooked? Any way other than the example file that I could try?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `IGNOREHEADER 1` option, Redshift will regard the first line as a header and skip it. If there is just one line in the file, you should take this option off.

If your file contains multiple records, you might have a data load error. Since you're specifying `MAXERROR 30`, Redshift will skip invalid records up to 30 records and return success result. The load error information during the copy would be stored in STL_LOAD_ERRORS table. Try  `SELECT * FROM STL_LOAD_ERRORS order by starttime desc limit 10;` to check if you had load errors.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of the ignoreheader issue.  Now the examples worked.  Great catch.  This led me to move to other possibilities.  Finally, I just removed the header row and it worked.  I have no idea why!  I usually have headers and ignoreheader works without any problem.

Comment: I should have checked the stl_load_errors.  Whenever I've had errors in the past, if they didn't break the 30 threshold, the table would still load.  For some reason, it was trying to validate the header row with the column types.  So basically, I was getting that string type != int type.